# ng-change is not working properly with ng-if

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

### 1. java script which is called

```
this.changeRole=function(user){
    alert(user)
    if(user=='Admin' || user=='Subject Manager'){
     $scope.role=false;
    }
    else{
        $scope.role=true;
    }
  }
```

### 2. html from that function is called

```
 <div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Role
        <span class="text-danger">*</span>
    </label>
    <div class="col-sm-9">
        <select class="form-control" ng-model="uc.newuser.role"
                ng-change="uc.changeRole(uc.newuser.role)" required >
            <option  ng-repeat="role in uc.roles" ng-value="user.name" >
              {{role}}
            </option>
        </select>
    </div>
 </div>
```

```
<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>User Name</th>
          <th>E-mail ID</th>
          <th>Mobile</th>
          <th>User type</th>
          <th ng-if="role=='Admin'">Action</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="user in users">
          <td>{{user.name}}</td>
          <td>{{user.email}}</td>
          <td>{{user.phone}}</td>
          <td>{{user.role.toString()}}</td>
          <td ng-if="role=='Admin'">
            <button class="btn btn-circle btn-gout1"
                    ng-click="uc.editUser(user.id)"
                    data-toggle="modal"
                    data-target=".bs-register-modal-md">
              <i class="fa fa-pencil"></i>
            </button>
            <button class="btn btn-circle btn-gout"
                    ng-click="uc.deleteUser(user.id)">
              <i class="fa fa-trash"></i>
            </button>
          </td>
        </tr>


    </tbody>
</table>
```

3. After ng-change the column with ng-if is hiding.

Answer (score 1):

ng-if should be checked like

```
<td ng-if="role">
```

Comment: No i have some roles for which i need to provide edit delete option, so I am mentioning that role in ng-if

Comment: Thank you, i was not differentiate both the roles, after u asked about that, i got to know and i changed one role to projectRole now it is working fine.

Comment: Mark if that helped

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly sure on what actually is required. However, this is what I think:

The select dropdown decides the role and based on the role the actions should appear on the following set of users.

You could directly use `ng-model` to do the same.

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp',[]);

app.controller('Ctrl',function($scope){
    $scope.selectedRole = 'ADMIN'
    $scope.roles = ['ADMIN','Subject Manager','Student'];
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="Ctrl">
 <div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Role
        <span class="text-danger">*</span>
    </label>
    <div class="col-sm-9">
        <select class="form-control" ng-model="selectedRole"required >
            <option  ng-repeat="role in roles" value="{{role}}">
              {{role}}
            </option>
        </select>
    </div>
 </div>
 <table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>User Name</th>
          <th>E-mail ID</th>
          <th>Mobile</th>
          <th>User type</th>
          <th ng-if="selectedRole === 'ADMIN'">Action</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="user in users">
          <td>{{user.name}}</td>
          <td>{{user.email}}</td>
          <td>{{user.phone}}</td>
          <td>{{user.role.toString()}}</td>
          <td ng-if="selectedRole==='ADMIN'">
            <button class="btn btn-circle btn-gout1"
                    ng-click="uc.editUser(user.id)"
                    data-toggle="modal"
                    data-target=".bs-register-modal-md">
              <i class="fa fa-pencil"></i>
            </button>
            <button class="btn btn-circle btn-gout"
                    ng-click="uc.deleteUser(user.id)">
              <i class="fa fa-trash"></i>
            </button>
          </td>
        </tr>


    </tbody>
</table>
</body>
```

Comment: here, we are taking role as boolean once and role as string once.

Comment: So, here is what I think. from the dropdown you select the current role of the  user. If the role is admin, then the actions should appear?

Comment: No if i login as a Admin action should appear, and it is appearing, after ng-change is called, it is disappearing. But it should not happen

Comment: Then what is the change Role dropdown for?

Comment: Yess i got it Thank you, I changed one role to projectRole. Now it is working fine.

Comment: Yess i got it Thank you, I changed one role to projectRole. Now it is working fine.